# How to make a query to find this?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data like this in a table:

```
column1   column2
a         1
a         2
b         2
b         3
a         4
c         5
```

I want a output like this:

```
column1 column2
a       1-2
b       2-3
a       4-0
c       5-0
```

Comment: did you try group by and count

Comment: You need to be more detailed in explaining what you're trying to do. Why do we have two result rows with 'a'?

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
with vw1 as 
(select table1.*,rownum rn from table1),
vw2 as (select col1,col2,rn,rn - col2 dis from vw1),
vw3 as (select col1,min(rn),to_char(min(col2))||' - '||
case when min(col2) = max(col2) then '0' else to_char(max(col2)) end col2 from vw2
group by col1,dis order by min(rn))
select col1,col2 from vw3;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66804/1)

Comment: almost good. You missed one subquery since you had to sort data before getting rownum.

Comment: No, you didnt. here is corrected query:
with vw1 as 
(select col1, col2,rownum rn from (select test.column1 col1, test.COLUMN2 col2 from test order by test.COLUMN1, test.COLUMN2) ),
vw2 as (select col1,col2,rn - col2 dis from vw1)
select col1,to_char(min(col2))||' - '||
case when min(col2) = max(col2) then '0' else to_char(max(col2)) end col2 from vw2
group by col1,dis;

Comment: sqlfiddle works under MySQL and solution for MySQL will be a bit different I suppose. The point is that your query does not sort the data before getting rownum and in general it is wrong. On dataset from the question - it is ok, but try to add more data and you will see what is wrong.. try this dataset ('a', 1)('a', 2)('b', 2)('b', 3) ('a', 4) ('a', 5) ('a', 6) ('c', 5); You will see whats wrong with your query.

Comment: sorry, didnt see the oracle option there :) here you are: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae014/1/0 you can try your query on the same dataset and see the difference

Comment: You are welcome my friend, if you look at question, you will see the rows in your answer are different from the rows which shows as result in the question.

Comment: ok, I'm not sure how sqlfiddle works, but here is screenshot from my sqldeveloper https://www.dropbox.com/s/xj8gv7pnw1r7jpk/111.bmp and this is how it works in real life, not under some virtual Oracle schema. Hope now you understand what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given a lot of information.
- Will there always only be 1 or 2 values in column2, for each value in column1?
- Will column2 always be in order?
- etc, etc?

But, for the given data, the following should give the results you have asked for.

```
SELECT
  column1,
  MIN(column2)                                          AS first_column2,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE MAX(column2) END   AS final_column2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (                     ORDER BY column2, column1)  AS sequence_main,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2         )  AS sequence_c1,
    *
  FROM
    your_table
)
  AS sequenced_table
GROUP BY
  sequence_main - sequence_c1,
  column1
ORDER BY
  MIN(sequence_main)
```

Example calculations:

```
column1   column2   |  sequence_main  sequence_c1  main - c1  |  group
a         1         |  1              1            0          |  a1
a         2         |  2              2            0          |  a1
b         2         |  3              1            2          |  b2
b         3         |  4              2            2          |  b2
a         4         |  5              3            2          |  a2
c         5         |  6              1            5          |  c5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
select * from 
(
select col1 as column1,case when LEAD(col1 , 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY col2) = col1
then concat( LEAD(col2 , 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY col2),'-'||col2)   
else (case when lag(col1,1,0) over (ORDER BY col2) <> col1 then 
concat(col2,'-'||'0')else '0' end)
end as column2
from table
order by col2
)
where column2<>'0'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be carefull using something like

```
 select column1, column2, rownum from table1
```

to create some unique ids for your data. Per definition is the ordering without an **order by** in your SQL **not defined**. Therefore it is by coincidence that

```
select * from table1
```

returns your rows in the ordering you inserted it in your database. As the data grows you will get exceptions to this ordering. So it is **highly** recommended to put a primary key column in your data table to preserve this insert ordering.  I included the column `id` for this.

Using this pimped dataset you could get the requested data using this query:

```
with data_aggr as (
select column1,
case 
  when lead(column1,1,' ') over (order by id)<>column1
  and lag(column1,1,' ') over (order by id)<>column1
  then column2 || '-0'
  when lead(column1,1,' ') over (order by id)=column1
  and lag(column1,1,' ') over (order by id)<>column1
  then column2 || '-' || lead(column2,1) over (order by id)
  else null
end aggr_col2
from table1)
select column1, aggr_col2 from data_aggr where not aggr_col2 is null
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd24d/19